# RDP Session after lock timeout is blurry with no logon ability

Tags: remote-desktop, lock-screen

I have built a headless Windows 11 Pro client and use Remote Desktop to access.  When the lock timeout occurs, I have a blurred lock screen with only the accessibility and disconnect icons, no ability to log on.  This occurs 100% of the time.  If I close the session and open a new RDP session, I can then type in the password and logon.  Can someone explain why this is occurring and how to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue except RDP server is Win10. (My name is Greg as well.  Coincidence?)